# Structural design approaches ASD or LRFD

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

I have several questions regarding terminology as I get confused reading different sources. 
What I learned so far:

1. ASD is also called WSD (working stress design)
2. LRFD is also called Limit State Design (LSD) or ultimate load method.

I am sure #1 is correct. But I am not sure about #2. Can you help?

Also which one is called "Strength Design", ASD or LRFD?

Answer (score 3):

If you're reading sources referencing terminology other than ASD or LRFD, I'd stop reading them because they're outdated.

They're both limit state designs. See the article below.

ASD is considered strength design because it's a design approach centered around reducing the strength capacity.

https://www.bgstructuralengineering.com/BGDesign/BGDesign05.htm

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Actually I just found out that strength design is LRFD per what I see on page 1 of ASCE 7-10 (I thought the same way as you did though)